# Is there a difference between onerror in window and onerror in service worker?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, sentry

I want to add logging via sentry to the service worker. I'm worried that the some site may already have its own sentry and my sentry will conflict with it. I want to add logging via sentry to the service worker. I'm worried that the site may already have its own sentry and my sentry will conflict with it.

I want to add logging via sentry to the service worker. I'm worried that the site may already have its own sentry and my sentry will conflict with it.